# angular 2 check if model change on component

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

First, my code is working. This question is about if I am doing the proper thing and if I am using the power of angular 2. I come from angular 1 and still learning angular 2 core concepts.

Let's start:

Given an angular 2 app (RC.4) I have a calendar component which render a Calendar as view. Each calendar's day is "decorated" RED (busy) or GREEN (free) depending the result coming for an API rest call. If there is not data for a given day the day is not decorated at all.

So, I have the following Observable in calendar's @component. Once it is resolved, a property of the component "entries" is filled with the response. (The response is an array of day objects with a property "dayStatus" set to busy / green).

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.calendarService.getAll().subscribe(
            response => {
                this.entries = response.json();
            }
        );
    }
```

The calendar template has a ngClass which resolves to decorateDay() handler:

```
<span class="day" *ngFor="let day of week.days"
      [ngClass]="decorateDay(day)">
        {{ day.number }}
</span>
```

Every "day", therefore, in a declarative way looks if it should be decorated green or red through the handler decorateDay(day). 
It works as follows: "day" is passed as parameter and is used as key for retrieving the relevant object from the JSON array. From the object property a string green / red is passed to the view and decorated by CSS using ngClass.

```
  decorateDay(day) {

       let dayFormatted = day.date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

       //when observable was resolved entries is not undefined.
       if (typeof this.entries !== 'undefined') {
           let data = this.entries[dayFormatted];
           if (typeof data !== 'undefined') {
               return data.dayStatus;
           }
       }
   }
```

**And here comes my question:** I don't know when "entries" will be defined so **I check in the handler if undefined.** Looks like when the entries is filled the component *Magically* recheck again the handler (through change detection). I am ok with that BUT, There is not a better way of checking when a property of the component has changed? Maybe decorating the property with @resolved or using a lifecycle hook..? I don't like the way I am doing it!

Hope some of you can give some pointers. Thanks in advance!

PS: The binding with the model property could be done on the template itself but I want to use a handler because it gives me more flexibility about how to decorate the given day in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I might misunderstand your question but this seems to me is what you're looking for.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.calendarService.getAll().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.entries = response.json();
            // >>> here you know that `entries` was updated
            // just invoke what you want to be executed when `entries` has changed
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Günter You did not misunderstand the question. Certainly I thought about this. The problem I see is that I can not bind the handler decorateDay() to the view from inside the subscribe clousure, right?... On the other hand, I would prefer not to put all the logic inside the subscribe function... In angular 1 for example I would have broadcasted an event in a promise after is completed and a controller method anywhere else would have been listening for the event and starting the process to decorate the view...  Maybe I am complicating myself too much ^^ thanks for your hint anyway!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by binding but for the rest, just use observables. See for example https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html about how to use them.